# CSS set QTableView background color?

Tags: c++, css, qt, qtableview

I want to set the background color of all cell in a `QTableView` Object using css.

something along the lines of...

```
ui.tableView->setStyleSheet("QTableView { background-color: red; color: yellow");
```

Is this possible? If so how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the css attribute to "background-color", and then your example looks good to go.

Reference:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-reference.html

Comment: After correcting the example I gave it still does not work. Also I've been follow that reference all along and it shows (for `QTableView`) how to set the `gridline-color` and the color of the cells when selected. But I'm still left with my original problem here.

Comment: Have you tried setting the stylesheet on your main window, so that it affects all QTableView?

Comment: The Orginal code words just fine. I was overriding the setting in my Model with the default. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following piece of qss can do the trick:

```
QTableView::item {
      border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
     border-top-color: transparent;
     border-bottom-color: transparent;
 }
```

Most of the qss examples for QTreeView work also for QTableView

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview